# Error trying to quickstart magentoe 2.0

Tags: php, apache, magento

Got this error trying to quickstart magento 2.0 theme:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor\composer/../magento/module-ui/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor\composer/../magento/module-ui/registration.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor/magento/zendframework1/library;C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator;C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor/phpunit/phpunit;C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor/symfony/yaml;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ethel-ng\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71

I am using the latest version of xampp which supports php 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-dump the composer autoload: `composer dump-autoload`